# What is the fastest way to level past 95 in Diablo II?

Tags: diablo-ii

My sorc is level 95 right now and I calculated that I need around 200 baal runs on players 8 to get to level 96. That takes quite a long time. Anyone else has experience with leveling high level characters in diabo? What is the fastest way to do that?

Are level 85 areas still worth it (pits, ancient tunnels, ...), since the level difference is 10 levels now and the experience gain is 5% from normal monsters and a bit more from champions / bosses / minons.

Comment: does D2 have anticheat systems to prevent automation? otherwise it would probably take less time to just write a little script to kill whatever while you're sleeping

Comment: well, online there is because automated bots ruined the game. Items had no value anymore because bots collected tons of them. Since I play single player I don't see the point, if I could just use Heroeditor and  get whatever level I like.

Comment: don't forget about the exp shrines...

Comment: not worth it imo... you get cursed so quickly in pretty much any area, but especially at baal with decreptify...

Comment: @MaximeCuillerier or by the knights in chaos sanctuary

Comment: Well you might not like it but you go in games where bots run baal (or a friend if you want to be 100% legit) with teleport its easy, and you hide further away and there you go. you can always have the other 2 handed staff that gives exp as well

Comment: @MaximeCuillerier Yes, thats a good idea for online games. If your strength is not needed to defeat baal, you can even search an exp shrine, put on the +10% exp gain staff (I think it was Ondals Staff) and equip an Anni with 10% exp gain. In single player you cannot do that unfortunately...

Comment: @PaulErlenmeyer Ondal's Wisdom only gives 5% exp

Answer (score 19):

TLDR; Baal runs for weeks. Don't do it.

It's a slog, but Baal runs are the best way to level after patch 1.10. It used to be Hell Cow Level (if it even exists) pre 1.10. Some people do Chaos runs because it's more fun and they don't have to wait for Baal to summon his minions. There are bots on Battle.net that run both Baal and Chaos runs all day every day.

The time it takes to go to the other iLvl areas is not worth it, especially on battle.net, because your map will be random and you won't find it in a relatively short time. You're better off just teleporting to Baal.

If you are playing single player, teleporting to Pit and Tunnels IS worth it, because your map doesn't change.

Most people get to 90-95 and make a new character because it literally takes hundreds of hours and if you ever die, you just added another 30 hours because of the EXP loss.

Comment: What do you mean "buying as many Annihilus charms you can"?  It says on the page you can only have 1 at a time in effect? Did you mean trying to get all 3 of them?

Comment: You can have 1 annihlius charm at a time and it can have a max of 10% bonus xp gain. I've seen a video where a youtuber called dbrunski analyzed this topic and found that a level 98 character should only run diablo runs, because he is literally the only thing that gives xp. And a diarun is way faster than a baalrun. I havent done the maths on it and I really can't tell.

Comment: My bad, my plugy instance allows me to have as many unique charms as I can carry, so I forgot about the limit on vanilla diablo.

Comment: does D2 have anticheat systems to prevent automation? otherwise it'd probably take less time to just write a little script to kill whatever while you're sleeping

Comment: @hanshenrik yes they do. There are bots that still run all the time though but you risk a lot